# Unable to rewrite url for MVC project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am stuck here i have tried googling but couldn't find solution

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php|style.css|img\.png$ - [L]
   # RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

When i hit url `http://localhost/moviestock/home/index` `print_r($_GET)` then i got this output `Array ( )` that means `$_GET == array()` but i want $_GET like this `$_GET == array('controler'=> 'home', 'action' => 'index' )`  it is similar to `http://localhost/moviestock/index.php?controler=home&action=index` please give me any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try theses lines in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|png)$
RewriteRule moviestock/([^/])+/([^/])+/?$ moviestock/index.php?controler=$1&action=$2
```